# Streams and AudioAttributes at Automotive OS

Tags: android-automotive

We try to adapt our navigator application for Android Automotive OS and we see that if we use `STREAM_MUSIC` for navigator notifications then it doesn't mix with FM-radio.
If we use `STREAM_NOTIFICATION` then navi does mix with FM-radio, but there is no way in Android Car Settings to change `STREAM_NOTIFICATION` volume.
Do we understand correctly that streams doesn't map to AudioAttributes in Automotive OS automatically and all navigator applications will have to move to `USAGE_ASSISTANCE_NAVIGATION_GUIDANCE` to run properly on Automotive OS?

Comment: I've found that "Android automotive implementations should control volume using a hardware amplifier instead of a software mixer. " So it seems that AudioManager does software mixing internally and that's somehow hard to support hardware amplifier in terms of existing and deprecated streams API in AudioManager?   https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/audio/audio-control#configure-volume

Answer (score 1):

You should use usage and content audio attributes in your application instead of legacy stream types.

Stream types like `STREAM_MUSIC`, `STREAM_NOTIFICATION`, etc. are superseded by [AudioAttributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes) for defining the behavior of audio playback and most of the stream-based API is already deprecated - one exception in regular Android is volume control (refer to [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager) and methods like `setStreamVolume`, `adjustStreamVolume`, etc.).

But in Android Automotive implementations the Android Framework is configured to use fixed volume policy which means there's also no stream-based volume control. Actual volume control is expected to be realized by Audio HAL or hardware amplifier (refer to [Android Automotive Audio](https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/audio/audio-control#configure-volume) documentation) and for such case there's a separate volume control API based on volume groups in [CarAudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/media/CarAudioManager).

Please also remember that before starting an audio stream, the application should request audio focus using the same audio attributes as it will use for its audio stream.

Simplified example:

```java
AudioAttributes playbackAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .build();

MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource( /* ... */);
player.setAudioAttributes(playbackAttributes);
player.prepare();

AudioFocusRequest focusRequest = new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
        .setAudioAttributes(playbackAttributes)
        .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener( /* ... */)
        .build();
int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(focusRequest);
if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
    // Respect audio focus
    player.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply! In my opinion it's quite unusual that in this case deprecated means "not supported at all" https://source.android.com/devices/audio/attributes#deprecated I thought that it's possible to map stream types to AudioAttributes the same way as they are getting mapped in https://github.com/Rayduh/support/blob/master/media-compat/java/android/support/v4/media/AudioAttributesCompat.java#L702